# d3 equivalent of jQuery parent()

Tags: jquery, svg, d3.js

I have various SVG `<g>` objects, each with a `<circle>` child and a `<text>` child. I can use `select()` to find a particular `<text>` object, by the class attached to it, and then modify it:

```
d3.select('text.my-class')
    .classed("my-class",false).classed("new-class",true)
    .text("Next Stage!")
    ;
```

Now I need to modify it's circle sibling. The circle has no particular identifying class (hhmmm... perhaps giving it one would be the d3 way of doing this?), so my first try was jQuery-like:

```
d3.select('text.my-class').parent().select('circle')
    .attr('style','fill:#f00;')
    ;
```

That fails with "parent is not a function".

The answer to a similar question ( [How to select parent element of current element in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20641953/841830) ) suggested `this.parentNode`, but either I'm using it wrong or it does not work here. I've tried both of these:

```
d3.select('text.my-class').select(parentNode).select('circle')
d3.select('text.my-class').select(this.parentNode).select('circle')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

D3 don't have a method to access parent nodes. You can access the DOM node of a selected element using the `node()` method. This element will have the `parentNode` attribute:

```
var textNode = d3.select('text.my-class').node(),  // DOM node
    parentNode = textNode.parentNode,              // Parent DOM node
    parentSelection = d3.select(parentNode),       // Selection containing the parent DOM node
    circle = parentSelection.select('circle');     // selection containing a circle under the parent selection
```

In a callback, you can use:

```
d3.select('text.my-class')
   .on('mouseover', function(d) {
      // The 'this' context is set to the DOM element, not the selection
      var circle = d3.select(this.parentNode).select('circle');
      circle.attr('fill', 'red');
   });
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks! I used `var textNode = d3.select('text.my-class');` and then `d3.select(textNode.node().parentNode).select('circle').attr('style','fill:#f00;')` and it appears to be working so far. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
selection.select(function() { return this.parentNode; });
```

You can also just add your own .parent() method to `d3.selection.prototype`:

```
d3.selection.prototype.parent = function() {
    return this.select(function() { return this.parentNode; });
};

// example!
d3.selectAll(".child").parent().each(function() {
  console.log(this.className);
});
```

[demo on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/loriv/1/edit)