# how to select parent div of svg in D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have read several articles and tutorials but couldn't find a sufficient answer on how to select the parent div of the svg using d3.select. I basically just want to append a tooltip to the div which contains my chart like this.

```
//this selection probably doesn't make sense...
var tooltip = d3.select("#pie-svg").select(this.parentNode).append("div")
            .attr("class", "piechart-tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the lines of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641953/how-to-select-parent-element-of-current-element-in-d3-js):

```
var tooltip;
d3.select("#pie-svg").each(function() {
  tooltip = d3.select(this.parentNode).append("div")
        .attr("class", "piechart-tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);
});
```

The problem with the code you've posted in the question is that `this` won't be defined (or set to the right element) in this context. When used with `.each()`, it will.

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. But I am now facing a problem of adding the tooltip to the correct place because before I would use d3.event.pageX and .pageY to get the mouse coordinates but now I need to know the coordinates relevant to the parent div of the svg. I tried using a similar approach and with mouse(container) but in the console it says 'undefined is not a function' so it doesn't recognise the parent div. I will post my code below so you can have a look.

Comment: I just tried mouse(this) and that does not return undefined. I am assuming the problem is because I cannot pass a parentNode as a container.. Have you got any suggestions on how I can work around this to be able to pass the div container to mouse() ? The div container is actually being resized dynamically as my window shrinks and I don't want to use mouse(this) because that doesn't always give me the correct position.

Comment: You could use absolute positioning for the tooltip and then still `pageX` and `pageY`.

Comment: I'm already using absolute positioning but it still completely goes off the container.

Comment: Could you post a complete example that shows the problem please?

Comment: I don't have access to all of the files on the database I am afraid and it would probably take me 2 hours to prepare a jsfiddle anyway... Are you perhaps familiar with the mouse(container) function? If I manage to correctly pass in the parent div in there then that would solve my problem..

Comment: I just tested it and I can see that the temp contains the reference to the div. I think the "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function " is because it doesn't accept a type like this.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is caused by this line?

Comment: yes because if I comment it out there is no problem.

Comment: what does parentNode actually return? is it the direct reference to the div or is it contained somewhere in an array of objects?

Comment: The direct reference.

Comment: If I do console.log(parent) (temp is the same as parent) this is what I'm seeing http://i.imgur.com/DqpDpUm.jpg

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a complete example.